# Locking user in SQL using MVC

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I would like to lock a user from the aspnetusers database in SQL using MVC.
This is my admin controller:

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LockUser(string Id)
    {
        var datastore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>();
        var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser, string>(datastore);
        //update current user object in memory
        //var user = User.Identity.GetApplicationUser();
        var user = manager.FindById(Id);
        user.LockoutEnabled = true;
        user.LockoutEndDateUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(2);
        manager.UpdateAsync(user);
        var dbcontext = datastore.Context;
        //update user object in database
        dbcontext.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

This is my admin view:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("LockUser", "Admin", new { id = x.Id }))
 {
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Lock" />
 }
```

When I click the button nothing happens in my Database and I can still login with the account.
I get this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context.
  Source=EntityFramework
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.UpdateEntitySetMappingsForType(Type entityType)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.FindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Object[] keyValues)
       at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.FindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Object[] keyValues)
       at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.FindAsync(Object[] keyValues)
       at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.EntityStore`1.GetByIdAsync(Object id)
       at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`6.<GetUserAggregateAsync>d__6c.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.AsyncHelper.RunSync[TResult](Func`1 func)
       at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManagerExtensions.FindById[TUser,TKey](UserManager`2 manager, TKey userId)
       at BlogMaxim.Controllers.AdminController.LockUser(String Id) in C:\nmct\2e Jaar\1e sem\project\BlogMaxim\BlogMaxim\Controllers\AdminController.cs:line 70
       at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
       at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Did you try to debug it?

Comment: It says that the 'var us' is null. I don't understand how this can be null though.

Comment: Try to use this in first line instead of the current one: `var datastore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext());` Also, make sure that the dataStore points to the correct database which you can know by debugging through your code I suspect your database connection string is not being used by the ASP.Net identity framework.

Comment: You can also force your database connection string to be used by using this for first line: `var datastore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext(myConnectionString));`

Comment: You need to get the myConnectionString from your web config file.

Comment: Also makes  sure the database you are using to store user data, contains the correct tables and  columns according to ASP.Net Identity requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code when updating using `UserManager`. You need to call `SaveChanges` method on the database context in order to persist changes, else it will not persist in database.

```
var datastore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>();
var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser,string>( dataStore);
//update current user object in memory
//var user = User.Identity.GetApplicationUser();
var user = manager.FindById(Id)
user.LockoutEnabled = true;
user.LockoutEndDateUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(2);
manager.UpdateAsync(user);
var dbcontext = datastore.Context;
//update user object in database
dbcontext.SaveChanges();
```

Include the following namespace at top of your code. Also, in such cases you can just place the cursor in left corner of the red underline and click on the icon to bring up suggestions by Visual Studio.

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using  Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
```

Add references to following assemblies: `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.dll and Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.dll`

Comment: Can you just place your cursor on the left corner of red underline and Visual Studio will automatically give you a suggestion for the namespace to include.

Comment: I added the namespaces for you in my answer.

Comment: I'm aware of the namespaces and they were already added to this solution, still getting these errors: http://puu.sh/mux9v/2d11d721ee.png

Comment: You need to add references to the assemblies that contains these namespaces. (Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.dll and Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.dll)

Comment: Then remove these nuget packages and re-install them.

Comment: After deleting them and restarting VS, rebuilding the solution, when I try to re-install them it says in the Package Manger that this already has been installed, when I look in the references it's gone as I've deleted it?

Comment: I have made a minor change in my code where the `MyDbContext` is removed. Please try with latest code.

Comment: Did you uninstall them from NuGet Package manager? You need to uninstall them using NuGet Package Manager and not just deleting the files.

Comment: Yes I did, works all fine now, but the UserManager needs 2 params as stated here, what is this Key? http://puu.sh/muAcV/4542c7b458.png

Comment: Can you paste the line of code where this error is coming from? In other words what is line#67 in your code?

Comment: Try this code instead of line you pasted: `var usermanager = new UserManager<User>(new UserStore<User>(dataStore));   `

Comment: type or namesapce could not be found on 'User'

Comment: Use the standard approach to get suggestions for namespace in Visual Studio.

Comment: Try this: `var usermanager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser,string>( dataStore);`

Comment: Can you put your new code in your original post else it is impossible to know what's going on?